# Как посчитать длину отправленного альбома пользователем?(питон pytelegrambotapi)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, api

Даже, отправляя альбом фоток, он считает content_type как photo, а ни media_group

Comment: А как вы его отправляете?

Comment: Через media_group, и он не принимает почему то саму группу фоток

Comment: Код, Арчибальд! где код?.. у Вас на вопросе сейчас стоит 4 голоса за закрытие. Остался еще один голос и ваш вопрос закроют. И закроют абсолютно обосновано! Потому что на Ваш вопрос невозможно ответить. Вы говорите, что когда вы что-то делаете - результаты не соответствуют вашим ожиданиям, но вы почему-то не хотите показать, а как именно вы это делаете. Не надо так